# Overwriting existing column with cast generates single repeated column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm very new to tsql, and I am trying to overwrite an existing column with a new casted version (string to numeric). However, the new column has the first casted value repeated throughout the column instead of all casted values.

What is causing this behavior? When I run the subquery separately all casted values are shown.

[image]

```
UPDATE #temp 
SET #temp.[year] = a.[year]
FROM 
    (SELECT CAST([year] as int) as [year] FROM #temp) a

-- will generate the below output
```

[image]

Comment: You have 2 instance of `#temp` in your `UPDATE`, so your assigning *every* value to the column `year` in your `UPDATE` and one arbitrary value remains.

Comment: You want a ["simple" UPDATE statment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-a-simple-update-statement).

Comment: The last row is not showing in the screenshot of the output.  I'm not sure if that's a copying error or something in the query, hopefully it is a copying error.

Comment: I see. Thank you all. @larnu I only see one distinct value though in the new output.

Comment: Also, however, note that casting the value is somewhat pointless. If you `INSERT`/`UPDATE` a `varchar` column with an `int` value, the `int` is still stored as a `varchar`.

Comment: Perhaps what you actually want to do is change the data type of the column?

Comment: It looks like you want to change the data type from string to integer, you cannot do it that way, you'll need to use alter table and alter column to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the simple update query as below, otherwise you have to use join in that way which is not meaningful in your case

```
UPDATE #temp SET [year] = CAST(CAST([year] AS int) AS varchar(30))
```

Comment: Though this'll work, it'll do nothing to the data. The OP states that `year` is a `varchar`, so inserting a `CAST` value of `year` (to an `int`) is going to end up with the same value. Effectively you would end up with `CAST(CAST([year] AS int) AS varchar(30))`

Comment: I voted yes because the sample could have values where year is 2015.0 as a string value.